# Different APKs for phone and tablet

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multiple-apk

I have a large number of drawables in my app. If I use the same apk for both phones and tablets the apk size would be too large. Hence I am trying to create two different apks - one for phones and one for tablets.
I am doing this on android studio in the gradle file. I have created two different flavors 'phone' and 'tablet' for the same.

I want to include only the drawable folder for the flavor 'phone' and I want to include the folders drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp for the flavor 'tablet'. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to include only the drawable folder for the flavor 'phone' and I want to include the folders drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp for the flavor 'tablet'. How do I achieve this?

Use the flavor-specific source directories.

Assuming you haven't modified the default folder structure, move the drawable resource folders you want to variate from `src/main/res` to `src/flavorname/res`.

Note that it makes sense to have the default `res/drawable` for each variant, so consider naming one of your tablet configurations without the qualifier.

Comment: Works very well !! Thanks a lot !!